# How to Force FORMAT to use decimal representation

Tags: excel, vba

[image]I have this in my Excel VBA Function

```
    Result = Format(0.0000000001, "#0.0###")
```

I would like to get the value

```
    "0.0"
```

Instead I get

```
    "1e-09.0"
```

Is there any way to force the FORMAT function to round to a specified level of precision? Or is there some alternative to FORMAT that will do so?

Comment: remove the last `###`

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results.  `MsgBox Format(0.0000000001, "#0.0###")` displays `0.0`.  What are you not telling us?

Comment: I thought it might have been something about using it as a return value but I get the same using a message box.

Comment: You might want to include the entire function

Comment: Looks like Mac too, right?

Comment: Yep. Bill might be taking revenge on Steve.

Comment: that was the entire function less the function and end function statements.

Comment: Well, writing it into a function also returns `0.0` here.  But I don't have a Mac.  Have you installed all of the updates? (I read, many years ago, of someone on a Mac having an issue with the `Format` function that was resolved after installing the Excel/VBA updates.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:
\"0.0\"
Good luck